# Is integer immutable or mutable?

Tags: python

Int variables are immutable. So when an integer type is assigned to a new variable, it should create a new object, right? But it only creates a new object when changes are made to either variables. Are integers not immutable?  What am I missing?
Thank you!

```
x = 5
y = x
print(x is y)   #>>>True | So y is a reference.
print(y)        #>>>5

x +=1
print(x is y)   #>>>False | now y is an object? Is that it? 
print(y)        #>>>5
```

Comment: `x += 1` is shorthand (syntactic sugar) for `x = x + 1`, which makes it clear that `x` has been assigned a new value (which happens to be the result of adding 1 to its previous value). So it's clearly not the same as `y` any more. This has nothing to do with the fact that integers are immutable (which they are).

Comment: Yes, integers are immutable.  There are lots of other languages where they aren't, but Python does its best to hide the difference.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Not quite. `x += 1` is implemented with `x = x.__iadd__(1)`, if defined; otherwise, (as is the case with `int`) it is implemented with `x = x.__add__(i)`. So it *might* be shorted hand for `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are at play. First, int's are objects that can be bound to more than one variable. Second, python caches a small cluster of small integers that tend to be used a lot for efficiency

```
x = 5       # get the cached `5` object and bind it to x
y = x       # take whatever object is bound to x and also bind it to y
x += 1      # take whatever object is bound to x, call its `__iadd__` 
            # method and bind the return value to x. `int.__iadd__`
            # adds the integers and since it is small, returns the
            # cached `6` object.
```

Notice that assignment does not create a new object. It simply puts a reference to an object into a variable, much like adding a key/value pair to a dictionary.

Comment: The fact that small integers are cached is an implementation detail that is irrelevant to the question.  The sequence of events would be the same even for integers that aren't cached.

Comment: @MarkRansom - What? It is highly relevant in the discussion of identity (`is`) of small integers and can be confusing to people who run tests with small numbers and find that large ones behave differently. In this case, `x is 6` is True. Had the original assignment been `x = 1000`, `x is 1001` after the addition is False. OP was experimenting with the identity of small integers and the idea that knowing this special case is irrelevant is just plain wrong.

Comment: The question doesn't contain `x is 6`, it contains `x is y`.  The answer to `x is y` doesn't change based on caching.

Comment: @MarkRansom - And you don't think that OP will try other operations and test for identity? You must be an extreme minimalist. Using an identity test after augmented assignment is different depending on whether you get a cached int. Suppose OP does `x -= 1` and `x is y` is True again. Try to explain that without mentioning the caching of small ints.

Comment: It's OK to mention caching, but as an aside not as a critical part of the answer.  By conflating two different concepts you cause as much confusion as you dispel.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I don't think so. Small integers are different than most objects when it comes to reassignment and identity tests. And anyway, I put it as the second thing and made sure to note the details of how it was used in the comments. How is this not "mentioning it". (and I noticed how you have changed the argument from "irrelevant").

Comment: It is still irrelevant in regards to the question actually asked.  You've made the argument that further experimentation might lead to further questions, and I grant you that.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Quoting the question: _So when an integer type is assigned to a new variable, it should create a new object, right?_ That depends on whether its a small cached integer. You seem to be stuck on a narrow example of binding from an existing variable. But the question is larger than that.

Comment: The simple fact is that using `=` to change or create a variable *never* creates a new object; the object already exists based on what happened on the right-hand side.  Whether the object had to be created or simply reused truly is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkRansom - `x = 1000` creates a new object. `x = 5` does not create a new object. `+=` may or may not create a new object depending on how the object implements the method and whether you get a small cached integer. When using `is` to decide the conditions that create an object, knowing this is part of the story. At this point, just stop trolling my answer. I have clearly explained why I think that the information should be included.

Answer (score 4):

`x` and `y` are both references.

`x = 5` : `x` is a reference to `5`

`y = x` : `y` is also a reference to `5`

`x += 1` : `x` is now a reference to `6`, `y` is still a reference to `5`

Answer (score 4):

The integer is immutable.

When you write x=5, x points to a memory location that holds 5.

When you go on and code y=x, the variable y points to the same location as x.

Then you type x+1=6, and now x points to a new location that holds 6, and not the previous location. ( Here, the integer still holds immutable because the original integer 5 still exists, but the variable x is not bound to it now. x is now bound to a new location. But y is still bound to the integer 5)

But y still points to the same location that holds 5.

So, integers are still immutable and this is how it works.
To see it better, use id(x) or id(y) after every step.

Comment: The *variable* is not immutable; the `int` object *referred to* by the variable is.

Comment: Also, a shallow copy is exactly what the assignment does *not* do. A shallow copy of (e.g.) a list means you make a new list, but the the new list refers to the same objects as the original list. Say you have `x = [[1]]`. Then `y = x` makes no copy at all; `y = x[:]` or `y = copy.copy(x)` makes a shallow copy, where `x` and `y` are distinct lists but `x[0]` and `y[0]` refer to the same object; and `y = copy.deepcopy(x)` makes a deep copy: copies of *all* values are made recursively.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about that part and I'll correct that too

Answer (score 0):

Here's a diagramatic explanation. The crucial part is `x += 1` in fact creates a new object in memory with the value at `x`'s old reference plus `1` (which is `6`) in this case.

[image]

Comment: `x is y == True` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `x is y` is checking if `x` and `y` have the same identity - i.e. they point to the same memory address. Is that wrong?

Comment: It's a comparison operator chain, roughly equivalent to `(x is y) and (y == True)`

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is: In the semantics of python language, variable is pointer or reference, which points to an object. Variable could be changed or bound to any object, but the object itself is immutable (or mutable).

This is bit different from C, e.g. `int i = 10;` in which variable is itself object.